# ifstrempty Renders always False

Tags: etoolbox, strings

The following minimal example makes problems:

```latex
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\foo}{}
\begin{document}

    \ifstrempty{\foo}{True}{False} % This is always False
\end{document}
```

Why is `ifstrempty` always False?

Comment: `\ifstrempty` is exactly that: It converts the first argument to a string and checks whether it's empty. The string-representation of `\foo` (not its replacement text) isn't empty.

Comment: you want `\ifdefempty`.

Comment: Or this: `\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\foo}{}
\begin{document}
\ifx\foo\empty True\else False\fi
\end{document}`.  In this case though, `\foo` must be defined as short  (via `\newcommand*` or `\def`), not long (via `\newcommand` or `\long\def`).

Comment: @Skillmon, i'm looking at this from a programmers perspective, for me the first argument is None or EmptyString, which seems to be not correct, so what is "the first argument" and what is the converted string?

Comment: The first argument is the first balanced group (or single non-space token) you put after `\ifstrempty`, the string representation of it is the result of `\detokenize`, which (with standard settings) is `\foo ` (but all the displayed characters except the trailing space have category code 12). Note that many aspects of TeX are non-intuitive if you're looking at it from a "programmers perspective" (that is from the perspective of someone accustomed to imperative languages etc.), as arguments are not evaluated, TeX is a macro expansion language. You really want `\ifdefempty`.